# Is it possible to query TFS for tasks that went from Pending to Active within a certain timeframe?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to find a way to track the status of which tasks my team has started in the past week, and also which ones they've closed.  It looks like the Start Date and the End Date fields both have to be set in MS Project, which we don't use.  I was hoping there would be a way to write a query based on state transition dates, but I'm not seeing one.  Is there any way of getting the data my management wants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is, with [ASOF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nericson/archive/2010/03/08/tfs-2010-method-to-get-work-items-as-of-a-date.aspx) you can view the state of a query on a certain date.
Then simply compare them to 'now' or another ASOF in order to detect the transition you 're after.
Check also [this](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Time-travelling-with-Work-Item-Queries-In-TFS-2008.aspx) Hofman-post.